# Adobe Garamond Pro and Esperanto

Tags: fonts, garamond, esperanto

Is it at all possible to typeset text in Esperanto language (with `LuaLaTeX`) using Adobe Garamond Pro font? After some research and testing it appears there is no way to do this, that some characters (such as ĉ, ŭ, ĥ) are simply missing and impossible to create even with composite commands (like `\^ c`).

Or is there a way around it? Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit**
Upon request adding MWE:

```
%%%! lualatex

\def\fontBaseName{adobegaramondpro}
\def\fontBaseNameBold{agaramondprosemibold}

\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{esperanto}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={\fontBaseNameBold}]{\fontBaseName}
\begin{document}
Antaŭparolo

Ĉi-loke estas kaj fariĝis ŝoseo estas ŝtopita teĥnike
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I don't have the font so can't test, but do you mean it doesn't have the ^ accent at all? (you could take one from another font)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: it does have the accent, however if I try e.g. this `\^ o \^ g \^ h` I get ô g h, in other words it puts the accent over o but not over g and h.

Comment: Please show a minimal example of what you try to compile.

Comment: also show the full log for your test file, recent latex releases have tried harder to avoid problems in this area, so it depends on which version you have

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The log is quite long (659 lines), however it starts with `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.6.30)`.

Comment: Does it work with another font in your installation, eg. lmodern and with pdfTeX?

Comment: Try with another font. If it works, Garamond Pro doesn't have that character.

Comment: Yes, it does work with other fonts.

Comment: I have the font and it clearly reports "there is no 0302" (that's the accent) and similar for the accented glyphs.

Comment: There are two ways to get an accented character. One way is to overlap an accent with a base character. The other is to use a pre-composed single character. LuaLaTeX uses utf-8, which looks for the single Unicode character in question. But it is not in that font. Either change the font, or hand-make the overlap yourself using something such as `\rlap` and reverse kerning.

Comment: I don’t have that font, but [here is another question about overlaying non-combining accents.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476566/caron-accent-va-doesnt-render-without-usepackagexecjk) The same technique might work.

Comment: @Davislor: Thank you. I am using another very similar font, Linotype Garamond Premier for the Esperanto parts of the book. It works very well.

Comment: @MarcelS. Should’ve checked the date. Still,the link in the comment might be useful to someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a few years old, but I saw it when it landed back on the front page, and it deserves an answer.  Actually, it deserves two, depending on which problem you want to solve: getting those accents in Garamond, or faking accented characters in a font that does not contain them.

You update in the comments to say that you ended up using Linotype Garamond Premier.  In 2020, a free font that contains all these characters is EB Garamond.  Garamond Libre would also work.

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbering.
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{esperanto}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Antaŭparolo

Ĉi-loke estas kaj fariĝis ŝoseo estas ŝtopita teĥnike
\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond sample]

If you are looking instead for a solution to the problem that your font does not contain combining accents (rare these days, but [I have run into it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476566/caron-accent-va-doesnt-render-without-usepackagexecjk)), you can tell LaTeX to use non-combining accents.  A MWE for your sample:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbering.

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setdefaultlanguage{esperanto}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\DeclareTextAccent{\^}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"02C6} % Modifier letter circumflex accent
\DeclareTextAccent{\u}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"02D8} % Spacing breve
\newunicodechar{Ĉ}{\^{C}}
\newunicodechar{ĝ}{\^{g}}
\newunicodechar{ŝ}{\^{s}}
\newunicodechar{ĥ}{\^{h}}
\newunicodechar{ŭ}{\u{u}}

\begin{document}
Antaŭparolo

Ĉi-loke estas kaj fariĝis ŝoseo estas ŝtopita teĥnike
\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond with faked accents]

The Unicode standard says that canonically-precomposed and decomposed characters should be equivalent, but not every font on every system implements that correctly.  If a font you want to use contains combining accents, but a precomposed character does not work, delete the `\DeclareTextCommand` lines from the above example.