# Caron Accent \v{a} doesn't render without \usepackage{xeCJK}

Tags: xetex, fontspec, accents, xecjk, newunicodechar

I am encountering an odd problem. I want to create composite characters such as *ǎ* using the `newunicodechar` package. However, it only yields a result in combination with the `xeCJK` package.

This code produces missing characters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\v{ü}}
\newunicodechar{Ǚ}{\v{Ü}}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\v{a}}
\newunicodechar{Ǎ}{\v{A}}
\newunicodechar{ǒ}{\v{o}}
\newunicodechar{Ǒ}{\v{O}}


\begin{document}

ǚ Ǚ ǎ


\end{document}
```

If I load the `xeCJK` package then the characters render just fine. 
Why is that? And how to generate composite characters without the named package?

**Note:**

- this is reproducible with other fonts that do not contain the unicode characters (e.g. Adobe Garamond Pro)
- Minion Pro **does contain** a caron character (unicode 02C7, index 136)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default setup doesn't use unicode U+02C7, but the combining accent  U+030C which is missing in your font. xecjk contains some code to use U+02C7 instead, but seems to use this code only if xunicode is loaded too - which is a bit of a pain, as normally one shouldn't use it anymore.

You can clone the xeCJK code by using `\add@accent`. If more fonts are involved where some have the combining accent, some  additional checks for glyph existence are probably needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\makeatletter

\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\add@accent{`^^^^02c7}{ü}}
\newunicodechar{Ǚ}{\add@accent{`^^^^02c7}{Ü}}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\add@accent{`^^^^02c7}{a}}
\makeatother
%\newunicodechar{Ǎ}{\v{A}}
%\newunicodechar{ǒ}{\v{o}}
%\newunicodechar{Ǒ}{\v{O}}
%
\begin{document}
abc 

ǚ Ǚ ǎ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As always you're answering my questions :)
Could this be a potential feature request for `newunicodechar`: Substitute combining characters automatically?

Comment: No, newunicodechar doesn't care about the code you use, you could also input a picture. But you make a feature request for latex, the kernel could perhaps add a fall back to 02c7 to the definition of \v.

Comment: Are you sure I can just submit it to the Latex2e github?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [a trick by Egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41148/61644), this uses the `\accent` primitive.  I chose to simply redefine `\v`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}

\renewcommand\v[1]{\accent\string"02C7 #1}

\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\v{ü}}
\newunicodechar{Ǚ}{\v{Ü}}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\v{a}}
\newunicodechar{Ǎ}{\v{A}}
\newunicodechar{ǒ}{\v{o}}
\newunicodechar{Ǒ}{\v{O}}

\begin{document}

ǚ Ǚ ǎ Ǎ ǒ Ǒ

\end{document}
```

[image: ǚ Ǚ ǎ Ǎ ǒ Ǒ]

I picked Cardo as a common font that contains the caron accent, but not the precomposed ǚ.

Comment: I can reproduce the MWE of this solution with Minion Pro. However, for some reason it doesn't work in my actual main file. There is some clash with another package, and I cannot identify (yet) which one it is.

Comment: You might to change the `\documentclass` back, if you didn’t. I switched to `standalone` for the convenience of creating a cropped image. Anyway, just adding the line `\renewcommand\v[1]{\accent\string"02C7 #1}` ought to work.

Comment: I already checked and your solution definitely works with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}`
Must be something else...

Comment: I also removed `xunicode`? Or maybe it’s related to `\setmainfont` versus `\babelfont`?

Comment: I identified the conflicting package: it's `hyperref` 
But I have no idea what causes it

Comment: That package is notorious for not playing well with others.

Comment: It worked for me in TeX Live 2018 when I loaded `hyperref` last. (It’s generally a good idea to load `hyperref` as late as possible; it’s more likely to work that way.)

Comment: I loaded it last, using MikTex (hyperref package from Dec 2018)
This doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/yWzVAQP3

Comment: Make sure you’re up-to-date? If you still get the bug, maybe ask another question, because I can’t reproduce it by adding `\usepackage{hyperref}``.